# ReactJS: Dynamic previous & next buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and trying to understand how to accomplish a basic concept using best practices. The code below will render a list of items, when an item is clicked a stateful  component is toggled and data is passed from  to the  state object before being consumed by  on re-render.

What I need help with is a method to retrieve data from siblings from the array example below. Once the data has been fetched for previous/next projects that data should be accessible to the  component. Can these siblings be accessed with a key value? If so, how would I use key?

**DATA**:

```js
window.Seed = (function() {
  const projects = [
    {id:1, title:'Project 1', description:'Project 1 Description'},
    {id:2, title:'Project 2', description:'Project 2 Description'},
    {id:3, title:'Project 3', description:'Project 3 Description'}
  ]
};
```

**REACT CODE:**

```js
class ProjectList extends React.Component {

  state = {
    projects: [],
    isOpen: false,
    modalTitle: '',
    modalDescription: '',
    modalId: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ projects: Seed.projects });
  }

  handleModalOpen = (id, title, description) => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: true,
      modalId: id,
      modalTitle: title,
      modalDescription: description
    });
  };

  handleModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    const projects = this.state.projects;

    // GOAL #1: Pass previous/next project data as props
    // =================================================
    // Pass projects.map data from previous & next siblings
    // to the current component or explore a new method to 
    // retrieve data from state? I can already tell that this
    // probably is not the most dynamic approach to handle
    // previous/next data.

    const projectComponents = projects.map((project) => (
      <Project
        key={'project-' + project.id}
        id={project.id}
        title={project.title}
        url={project.url}
        description={project.description}
        background={project.background}
        onModalOpen={this.handleModalOpen}
        prevTitle={???}
        nextTitle={???}
        prevDescription={???}
        nextDescription={???}
      />
    ));

    if (this.state.isOpen) {
      return (
        <Modal
          id={this.state.modalId}
          title={this.state.modalTitle}
          description={this.state.modalDescription}
          onModalClose={this.handleModalClose}
        />
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div className="projects-container">
          <div id="projects" className="wrapper">
            {projectComponents}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

class Project extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <aside className='item'>
        <a onClick={this.props.onModalOpen.bind(
          this, this.props.id, this.props.title, this.props.description
          // I think that I need to bind previous/next data here on click.
          // this.props.prevTitle, this.props.nextTitle
          // this.props.prevDescription, this.props.nextDescription
        )}>
          <img src={this.props.background} />
        </a>
      </aside>
    );
  }
}

class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="modal">

        // GOAL #2: Get sibling data from mapped array
        // =================================================
        // I would like to be able to pass previous and next
        // project data as props to populate these headings.

        <h2>Current Project: {this.props.title}</h2>
        <h2>Previous Project: {this.props.prevTitle} </h2>
        <h2>Next Project: {this.props.nextTitle} </h2>

        // GOAL #3: Replace content with data stored in state
        // =================================================
        // I would like to be able to 'onClick' these buttons 
        // to replace the content of the <Modal />. Essentially,
        // this should behave like a lightbox or carousel.

        // Initial Project Description
        <p>{this.props.description}</p>

        // this.props.description = this.props.prevDescription
        <button onClick={???}>Previous Project</button>

        // this.props.description = this.props.nextDescription
        <button onClick={???}>Next Project</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.onModalClose}>Close Modal</button>

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/DRN4xW93x)**

Thanks for reading!

**[UPDATED SOLUTION](https://codesandbox.io/s/Rk360Yxz)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general principle, data should flow through React components from parent to child, not from sibling to sibling. In theory, it might be possible to pass data between siblings but this makes things orders of magnitude more complex. The beauty of the top-down data flow is that any time the data in the parent changes, the children will (probably, excluding optimizations like pure rendering) re-render. So you just have to change the data in the parent and the children will automatically update as they need to. Here are suggestions for approaching your goals this way. This isn't perfect but I hope it illustrates the point:

Goal #1: `Array.prototype.map` takes a function with these parameters: `function(currentValue, index, array) {...}`. For each project, the previous project is `array[index - 1]` and the next project is `array[index + 1]`. All you have to do is reference the previous and next projects this way in the map function to get their title, description, etc.

Goal #2: Instead of using `this.state.isOpen`, use `this.state.activeProject`. When the project is clicked, set `this.state.activeProject` to the index of that project. Then you can infer that the modal is open if `!!this.state.activeProject` (if `this.state.activeProject` is truthy). Use the `activeProject` id/index to pass desired data from that project to the Modal component in the `ProjectList` component render method.

Goal #3: Update `this.state.activeProject` to the index/id of the previous or next project. This will cause a re-render of `ProjectList` with the new props. To do this, you'll want to pass `onNextClick` and `onPrevClick` props. You can partially apply `this.state.activeProject + 1` and `this.state.activeProject - 1` to `onNextClick` and `onPrevClick`, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful reply. What you are saying makes sense to achieve my goals for this app, I guess that I have been doing so much "react-ive" coding that I completely neglected to use vanilla JS, thanks!

Comment: Here is my solution, do you mind telling me if my approach is okay or should it be refactored? If so, how would you optimize this data flow? [View Solution](https://codesandbox.io/s/Rk360Yxz)

Comment: Hey, I'd be happy to take a look. I'm not familiar with codesandbox.io. Is there a way to leave comments? If not, is this on Github or somewhere else I can leave feedback? I think we're beyond the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: I can put it up on GitHub. Thanks!!